# firestore transaction seemed to have allowed a concurrent edit?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We have been using this cloud function for a while where we provide our users with a single number/code from a array of unique locker numbers inside a single firestore document using the code as shown below.

```
function grabLocker(){
    return admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (t) => {              
        var lockerDoc = await t.get(lockerref);
        if(lockerDoc && lockerDoc.data()){
            var lockerArr = lockerDoc.data().lockers ? lockerDoc.data().lockers : [];                                       
            if (lockerArr.length > 0){
                var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*((lockerArr.length - 1)-0+1)+0);
                var newLockers = lockerArr.slice(0,randomIndex).concat(lockerArr.slice(randomIndex + 1));
                var userLocker = lockerArr.slice(randomIndex, randomIndex + 1);
                t.update(lockerref, {'lockers': newLockers});
                return {status: 'succes', locker: userLocker[0]};
            }
            return {status: 'empty'};
        }
        return {status: 'empty'};
    });
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the firestore document]

On our latest event this script gave 8 of the 600 users that requested a locker a duplicate number. We checked and double checked but the array only had unique numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional arrays should be avoided where possible. Based on your question, you seem to have at least 600 entries in the `lockers` array. Each time you write to the document in this transaction you end up having to shift the indexes of many entries in the array. So for each locker claimed, you'd remove one entry and shift up to 599 other entries. Cloud Firestore then has to reconcile this on the server side without getting a conflicting locker request.

This is inefficient and can lead to conflicts as discussed in this [blog post on Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.blog/posts/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase/).

The best approach (without redesigning your database) would be to reverse your array and use the `num` value (with the '.' substituted for a '-' to be compliant) as the key for each entry.

```json
{
  "lockers": {
    "28-001": {
      "beschikbaar": true,
      "code": "1694",
      "num": "28.001"
    },
    "28-002": {
      "beschikbaar": true,
      "code": "0957",
      "num": "28.002"
    },
    "28-003": {
      "beschikbaar": true,
      "code": "5192",
      "num": "28.003"
    },
    "28-004": {
      "beschikbaar": true,
      "code": "7830",
      "num": "28.004"
    }
  }
}
```

This means that `grabLocker()` needs to be edited to account for this change. We need to handle the new structure and use `FieldValue.delete()` to remove the now claimed locker. With this structure, it can be reconciled by Cloud Firestore faster than updating the index of each array entry.

```js
function grabLocker() {
  return admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (t) => {              
    const lockerDoc = await t.get(lockerref);
    const lockersObj = lockerDoc.get("lockers"); // lockerDoc always has a value, and `get(someField)` will return `undefined` if the document or the name field does not exist.
    const lockerKeyInfoArr = lockersObj ? Object.entries(lockersObj) : [];

    if (lockerKeyInfoArr.length === 0) {
      return {status: 'empty'};
    }

    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*lockerKeyInfoArr.length);
    const [lockerKey, lockerInfo] = lockerKeyInfoArr[randomIndex];

    t.update(lockerref, {
      [`lockers.${lockerKey}`]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete() // deletes this entry
    });
    return {status: 'succes', locker: lockerInfo};
  });
}
```